# Calling a module procedure that has a parameter of a class

Tags: vb.net, api, fedex

I am Writing a API for FedEx and our Universe database, the FedEx code has been written but i now need to create a string to write back to our Universe database.  The question is how would i make this tracking number into a variable so that i can use it in that string.  this is the procedure in the module:

```
Public Sub ShowTrackingDetails(ByRef TrackingIds() As TrackingId)
        ' Tracking information for each package
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Tracking details")
        If (TrackingIds IsNot Nothing) Then
            For Each trackingId As TrackingId In TrackingIds
                Console.WriteLine("Tracking # {0} Form ID {1}", trackingId.TrackingNumber, trackingId.FormId)

            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

in the for each method `trackingId.TrackingNumber` returns what i need.

Comment: Is your question about *calling a method with a class param* or returning some string from that for each?  Since it is a Sub, it wont "return" anything

Comment: well that's kind of what i was afraid of, but what if i stored that number in a variable within the procedure just while the code is ran.  is it possible i can use call that variable or something like it in my form class?  i only need that number one time, when the code is ran.

Comment: change it to a function to have it return something, but it can only return one thing.  Assuming `TrackingId` is a proper class, you could add code to return the ID in whatever format you need.  Still not sure what the actual question is

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ToString` method to convert a number to a string

```
Dim numberAsString As String = trackingId.TrackingNumber.ToString()
```

However, it is probably better to store numbers in a database as numbers rather than as strings.

If you want the variable to be available outside the `ShowTrackingDetails` method, you can declare it as Public or Private.

```
Private numberAsString As String
Public Sub ShowTrackingDetails(ByRef TrackingIds() As TrackingId)
    'your code
    numberAsString = trackingId.TrackingNumber.ToString()
    'your code
End Sub
```

Comment: but if i do this can i use that string variable somewhere else outside of the procedure?  that's what i would have to do

Comment: @chrisbahr: There are two ways to make the string available in a different method. The first is to use it as an argument when you call the method. The other is to declare the variable as `Private` or `Public` outside the `ShowTrackingDetails`method. I will edit my answer to include that.